# $E$ normed space and $F\subset E$ finite dimensional vector space implies there is point of minimum distance

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I have just now started studying these topics. The problem seems simple, but I am not managing to solve it.

I want to prove the following:

> Let $E$ be a normed space and $F \subset E$ a finite dimensional subspace of $E$. If $x\notin F$ then $\exists y\in F$ such that $d(x,F)=\parallel y-x\parallel$

I have $d(x,F)=\inf_{z\in F}\parallel x-z\parallel$.
I am trying to prove by contradiction, but I really don't know how to start. Can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a point $z\in F$ and let $r=||x-z||$. The set $K=\{w\in F\colon ||w-x||\le r\}$ is a non-empty, closed and bounded subset of $F$. Being $F$ finite-dimensional $K$ is compact. The function $d(w)=||w-x||$ is continuous and hence has a minimum on $K$ on some point $y$ with $d(y)\le r$. Such a point is the minimum of $d$ on the whole $F$ since points outside $K$ have distance larger than $r$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $d=d(x,F)$, for every integer $n>0$ there exists $x_n\in F$ such that $d(x,x_n)<d+1/n$. $d(x_1,x_n)\leq d(x_1,x)+d(x,x_n)\leq d+1+d+1/n\leq d+2$. We deduce that $x_n$ is an element of the closed ball $B(x_0,2d+2)\cap F$. Since this ball is compact, you can extract $x_{n_k}$ from $(x_n)$ which converges towards $y\in F$.
$d\leq d(x,y)\leq d(x,x_{n_k})+d(x_{n_k},y)\leq d+1/n_k+d(x_{n_k},y)$. This implies that $d(x,y)=d$ since $(x_{n_k})$ converges towards $y$.